# Crystal Reports: left outer join and filtering

Tags: crystal-reports

In Crystal Reports I'd like to join two tables on EmployeeId in a way that in the final result dataset I get EmployeeId where Type equals A or Type is null. I'd be easy to do it through command but I need to do it through table choice not command. When I left outer join the tables and filter records on condition Type=A or IsNull(Type) records with type value null are eliminated. Could you please advise how to do it?

**Table 1**

```
EmployeeId
1
2
3
```

**Table 2**

```
EmployeeId, Type
1, A
2, B
3, NULL
```

**Result set**

```
EmployeeId, Type
1, A
3, NULL
```

Regards,
Przemek

Comment: It's not isnull(type) instead it is type=null

Answer (score 1):

You just need to flip the order of the conditionals: `isnull(type) or type=A`. You always need to check for nulls as the first thing you do otherwise Crystal will treat it as an exception and won't continue to evaluate the statement.